# How to use the same password for multiple hardware encrypted SSDs?

Tags: ssd, encryption, uefi

I have recently updated storage on my PC, and the new drives support hardware encryption. I would like to use it, and it was fairly trivial to set up: click a couple things and enter a password in the UEFI.

However, given that I have 3 drives and would like all of them encrypted, I have to enter 3 passwords on boot, *even if the passwords are the same*. Can I configure UEFI to only prompt me once, and apply the same password to multiple drives - if so, how? (or, alternatively, only decrypt the drive I'm booting from and have the OS decrypt the rest - if that can work)

Relevant PC specs: MB: ASRock Z490 Taichi, SSDs: Samsung 970 EVO Plus 1TB x2 (M.2), Samsung 870 Evo 500GB (SATA3). BIOS version reads "American Megatrends Inc., P1.20, 15-Apr-20"

Comment: I found [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Self-encrypting_drives) on Arch wiki and apparently [SEDUtil](https://sedutil.com/) can do the pre-boot authentication instead of the UEFI. Still reading, will update if I figure it out

Comment: 3 weeks later and I still can't get sedutil to work - running into an issue after an issue after an issue.

TBH entering the password a billion times over in UEFI would probably be less trouble than using sedutil. I ended up using LUKS.